# CosmosDB: Pattern for storing relationship in a document and bulk Update/Delete performance

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking for a pattern to build security for structured JSON documents stored in CosmosDB. A document can be accessed by a set of user groups or individual users each with specific role per document. The role is mapped to CRUD permissions. I need to filter out documents by permission on querying documents and I am thinking of using an array within the document to store the permission information.

My concerns are following:

- Performance on removing the permissions. What is the impact of updating tens of thousands of documents?
- No transactions support when removing permissions across multiple documents. Instead of building transactions my own, what are the patterns available to avoid losing remove permission?

Comment: Note: sproc document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs says it is implementing transaction. I don't see anything like TransactionScope defined. Is it implicit? If there are multiple docs, do I need to follow this pattern with recursion?

Comment: The only transactional operation is that of a stored procedure, which is limited to a single partition within a collection. That said: your question is unfortunately too broad, asking for a per-document permission pattern. As for performance: if you're modifying thousands of documents, you'll need to benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from the CosmosDB engineering team. There aren't enough details to give an accurate answer, but feel free to follow up.

1. Performance on removing the permissions. What is the impact of updating tens of thousands of documents?

Replaces are heavier than creates, though this may not yet reflect in RUs today.

2. Transactions are supported within the boundary of a partition key. Please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#transactions for more details on implementing transactions using a stored procedure.
3. What are the patterns available to avoid losing remove permission?

Depending on whether there are concurrent permission updates expected to the same document(s), (re)application of permissions are idempotent. Assuming no concurrency, and x and x' are the current and new permission sets, re-applying (re-replacing) x' for all documents shouldn't have an effect in the event of a failure on issuing updates.

I also have a suggestion regarding managing a permission set per document - rather than duplicating the same permission set on multiple documents, did you consider grouping permission sets into permission 'groups', adding another layer of indirection to the actual permissions? You could maintain separate documents for each of these 'permission groups' that contain the actual set of user groups and/or users which are part of the permissions. Hopefully this should reduce the updates you do to the main documents themselves, and in many cases you could get away with updating just the document with the detail of the permission group.

Answer (score 0):

> Performance on removing the permissions. What is the impact of
>   updating tens of thousands of documents?

Based on your description, you need to change permissions of documents frequently.However, as i know, cosmos db sql api does not support partial update so far.(Please refer to my previous case:[How do you update sub-document in cosmos db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244543/how-do-you-update-sub-document-in-cosmos-db,nothing) updates so far) So,you need to operate entire documents with every operations.It is a costly work for you.

Per my knowledge,i suggest you using relational database.Store the permissions in a specific table and use it as the foreign key of the document.Maybe this is more suitable for you.

Comment: Note that it is not a frequent operation. When it happens, it can potentially span 100s or 1000s of doc. If it is RDBMS, I cannot do distributed transaction and need to implement 2 ph commit, isn't it?